# Filtered Colimit of associative $k$-algebras that are domains

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $C$ be a filtered subcategory of the category of commutative algebras over a fixed field $k$ whose objects are all integral domains. 
Then the colimit of the obvious diagram is an integral domain.
Does this statement also hold in the case where we drop the commutativity condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how commutativity matters.

Suppose $A$ is the filtered colimit of algebras $A_i$ and $x,y\in A$ with $xy=0$. Then $x$ is represented by $x_j\in A_j$ and $y$ by $y_k\in A_k$ for some $j$ and $k$. By "filtered", these map to elements $x_l,y_l\in A_l$ for some $l$ such that $x_ly_l=0$. Since $A_l$ is a domain, either $x_l=0$ (and therefore $x=0$) or $y_l=0$ (and therefore $y=0$).

Comment: I understand I'm a little late to the party here, but I am a bit confused by the answer here (I am new to category theory). What is meant by "$x$ is represented by $x_j\in A_j$" (similarly for $y$)? How do we represent an element of the colimit by an element of an object in $C$? And I understand how you've used the filtered condition, but how do we know that $x_ly_l=0$ in $A_l$?

Comment: @Dave The colimit $A$ of the $A_j$ comes with maps $A_j\to A$ for every $j$. By "$x$ is represented by $x_j$", I mean that $x\in A$ is the image of $x_j\in A_j$ under the map $A_j\to A$. For general colimits (of algebras, groups, ...), such elements generate $A$, but for filtered colimits, every element of $A$ is of this form for some $A_j$. And two elements $x_i\in A_i$ and $x_j\in A_j$ represent the same element of $A$ iff they map to the same element in some $A_l$ in the filtered system. This is essentially why filtered colimits have nicer properties than general colimits.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I guess I figured that "representing" was using the morphisms $\psi_j:A_j\to A$, but I suppose my confusion is how we know that there exists some $j$ such that $x$ is in the image of $\psi_j$? Also, if this is the case then we get $0=xy=\psi_j(x_j)\psi_k(y_k)$, and then there are maps $f:A_j\to A_l$ and $g:A_k\to A_l$ by the filtered condition, but how do we know that $f(x_j)g(y_k)=0$?

Comment: @Dave In any (not necessarily filtered) colimit $A$ of algebras (or groups, ...) is generated by (the images under $\psi_j$ of) the elements of the $A_j$, subject to relations stating that for any $f:A_j\to A_i$ in the filtered system, and any $x_j\in A_j$, $x_j=f(x_j)$. So any element of $A$ can be expressed in terms of elements of finitely many $A_j$. What the first part of the definition of "filtered" simplifies is that all of these $A_j$ map into a single $A_l$, and so your element of $A$ is represented by a single element of $A_l$.

Comment: @Dave If $x_j\in A_j$ and $y_k\in A_k$ represent the same element of $A$, then they map to the same element in some $A_l$. The key case is when $x_j=a(w)$ and $y_k=b(w)$ for some maps $a,b$ in the filtered system. Then there are maps $f:A_j\to A_l$ and $g:A_k\to A_l$, but it perhaps $fa\neq gb$, so $f(x_j)$ and $g(y_k)$ may be different. However, the second part of the definition of "filtered" says that there is a map $h:A_l\to A_m$ in the filtered system with $hfa=hgb$, and so $hf(x_j)=hg(y_k)$. So any equation that holds in $A$ holds in some single $A_m$.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for the clarification! It's all still new to me, so I'll keep thinking about this. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think I understand most of this now, but I am still having a hard time seeing why if $x_j\in A_j$ and $y_k\in A_k$ represent the same element of $A$ then they must map to the same element in some $A_l$?

Comment: @Dave Could you post a question (maybe on math.stackexchange) if you want more details? I'd be happy to answer, but writing explanations in comments is a bit of a pain! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on vacation. I have posted a question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403322/filtered-colimit-of-integral-domains-is-an-integral-domain. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated, and thanks for your help thus far.